# how can I passed my test when the programm takes no arguments and I tried to use @staticmethod before my function and nothing happend

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary, pytest

I'm a python beginner and I tried to pass my code in the pytest and nothing happens.
And appear the TypeError: read_products() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given. But my read_products function doesn't take any parameters. I tried to use @staticmethod before the function and includes "self" as a parameter and nothing happened. So please, Help me! The first link is my program and the second one is my test program.
https://codeshare.io/zy7nd4
https://codeshare.io/wnqKdx

Answer (score 0):

In your main file you have your function defined with zero parameters (which is what you want, if I understand correctly)

```py
def read_products():
```

However, when you call it from the test file, you call it with the argument `"products.csv"`

```py
def test_read_products():
    ...
    products_dict = read_products("products.csv")
    ...
```

Maybe what you want is to call it like this

```py
    products_dict = read_products()
```

Also, if possible please post your code in your question instead of an external site, thanks

Comment: Thank you for your attention and for answering me. God Bless